# How can I fix the problem in converting blade syntax to php? if statement in blade to php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have my code supported by Blade syntax in resources\views which is working then there is an automated coded from laravel framework in storage\framework\views written in PHP.

**Blade**

[image]

**PHP**

[image]

I am expecting to get the same result from blade syntax, but I have a syntax error converting to PHP

Answer (score 2):

you're getting an error cause when you use a blade directive, you don't need to use `{{ }}` to get a variable value, so the right syntax is:

```php
@if ( Auth::guard("employee")->check() )
...
@endif
```

one more thing, the `check()` method returns a boolean so you can't chain with the `user()` method. so what you need to do is

```php
@if ( Auth::guard("employee")->check() )
  <p>welcome {{Auth::user()->name}} !<p>
@endif
```